# How to pass value from a model in controller to other child controllers in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using AngularJS-UI Datepicker. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="form-inline date-picker" ng-show="is('home')">
            <div class="form-inline input-group">
                <input type="month" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="selectedDate" is-open="status.opened" min-date="reportDate.minDate" max-date="reportDate.maxDate" close-text="Close" /><p>{{ dt }}</p>

                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                </span>               
            </div>
        </div>
```

And my controller:

```
var mainController = monthlyReportApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'ReportDateService', '$state', function ($scope, ReportDateService, $state) {

    $scope.is = function (name) {
        return $state.is(name);
    }

    $scope.selectedDate = new Date();


    $scope.reportDate = [];
    $scope.currentMonth = 0;

    loadRemoteData();

    function loadRemoteData() {
        ReportDateService.list().then(function (response) {
            $scope.reportDate = response;
        });

    }

    $scope.getMonth = function () {

       console.log(angular.isDefined($scope.selectedDate) ? $scope.selectedDate.getMonth() : "nothing");
    }

    $scope.clear = function () {
        $scope.selectedDate = null;
    };

    $scope.open = function($event) {
        $scope.status.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.status = {
        opened: false
    };

    $scope.$watch($scope.selectedDate, function (newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log($scope.selectedDate.toDateString());
    })

}]);
```

The datepicker shows up just fine, and the input shows the month and year selected.

What I need to do now is the selected month and year should be passed on to other child controllers - there are many. But for some reason, I couldn't even make the selected month and year appear in the parent controller shown above. What am I doing wrong?

When I output the model like `{{ selectedDate }}` right below the datepicker, the value shows up.

Comment: you can pass the selected month and year to $rootscope and access them from anywhere

Comment: Can you show me how? I'm stuck here. I'm not even getting the value of the selectedMonth in the controller. I get `undefined`.

Comment: can you put your code in a plunkr or jsfiddle ?

Comment: think I figured it out. I used the ui-router $state and $stateParams to pass the values as parameter. Not so sure if that's the right way to do this, but it seems to be working. Still need to test it out. If someone can give me a quick tour on ui-router and passing the selected date as parameters using router and datepicker, that would be great. I was able to pass the values implicitly, but not using the datepicker model.

Comment: @MayK:  no no no no no no no no.  wrong.  you do not use `$rootScope` as a dumping ground.  if you need global stuff, you create a service and then inject it where you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, don't ever use $rootScope for stuff like that.

Second, the problem is you're storing the date on your controller's scope and not in an object.  You need to learn how scopes inherit in Angular.  More specifically, you're running into [this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/FAQ#my-input--select-element-doesnt-work-as-expected-inside-the-tab--accordion-directive).

Quick and dirty solution is to do `$scope.data = {}; data.date = new Date()` and then change `ng-model="selectedDate"` to `ng-model="data.date"` and your object will inherit correctly.